# from ASCII to usual numbers

Tags: assembly

I have some question about assembly, is it possible to convert ASCII code of numbers
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) without 10 `compares and branches` like

```
if(input == 48) return 0;
...
```

(I'm talkin about code on assembly!)
thanks in advance

Comment: For assembly questions you need to specify the CPU family.

Comment: I was thinking that the x86 processor had instructions to deal with this, but with further research it appears that the "ASCII adjust after addition" (AAA) instruction and related ones are just poorly named, they actually use BCD and not ASCII.  Silly intel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return input-'0';`

This, of course, given that input is a digit.
You can check it as follows, in C:

if(input >= '0' && input <= '9')....

Answer (score 2):

Just subtract 48 (the ASCII value for the character 0).

```
SUB EAX, 48
```

The exact syntax depends on the specific processor and the assembler you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an assembly guy at all but [this](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread164873.html) suggests you can use

```
sub     ebx, 48
```

to subtract 48 from your ascii code stored in the appropriate register. Of course this assumes intel assembly but I'd imagine others have similar functionality.

Comment: Sure, I'd also assume other assemblers have substraction ;P

Comment: Hey, if you're lacking subtraction, you can always just multiply by -1, and then add. :P